# Numpy broadcasting on multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a basis for a plane in 3 dimensions: (u, v).

I would like to obtain all linear combinations of this basis to basically go through my whole plane:

for i in [0, 512[ and j in [0, 512[, get all (i * u + j * v).

I need this to be fast so for loops are not really an option. How can I do that with numpy broadcasting?

Had a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html and my impression is that it's not possible to do...

Tried:

```
# This is an orthonormal basis but there is no guarantee it is
u = np.array([1, 0, 0])
v = np.array([0, 1, 0])
tmp = np.arange(512)
factors = itertools.combinations(tmp, 2)
pixels = factors[0] * u + factors[1] + v
```

But obviously it does not work.

Is there a solution to this problem? And if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply (u, v) with a 2D index grid:

```
ind = np.indices((512, 512))
pixels = ind[0, ..., np.newaxis] * u + ind[1, ..., np.newaxis] * v

>>> %timeit ind = np.indices((512, 512)); pixels = ind[0, ..., np.newaxis] * u + ind[1, ..., np.newaxis] * v
8.06 ms ± 69.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Multiply u with a 1D index range, multiply v with a 1D index range, broadcast and combine to 2D:

```
i512 = np.arange(512)[:, np.newaxis]
pixels = (i512 * u)[:, np.newaxis, :] + (i512 * v)[np.newaxis, :, :]

>>> %timeit i512 = np.arange(512)[:, np.newaxis]; pixels = (i512 * u)[:, np.newaxis, :] + (i512 * v)[np.newaxis, :, :]
4.06 ms ± 58.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example but it seems that this work in the particular case of my example. What if the basis is ([1, 1, 1], [1, -1, 1]) ?

Comment: The first example is a direct translation of the itertools combinations code you tried into only using numpy's `np.indices`. The second example uses the linear independence of the the first and second terms of `i * u + j * v` to speed up the computations. It should work for any values of `u` and `v`. Where exactly are you struggling to understand the solution?

Comment: Well the fact that you are using a "newaxis" on the x axis on u and "newaxis" on the y axis on v. I'm still relatively new to numpy so I need to review those concept.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html is a good resource for that, worth studying as well as the broadcasting page you mentioned.

Comment: Your solution works. In order to have something completely answering the question, like @blue_note's answer does, you just need to add a pixels.reshape((512*512), 3) at the end. Your solutions is the fatest.

Answer (score 1):

A few edits to your code

```
factors = itertools.product(tmp, tmp)
factors = list(zip(*factors))
factors = np.array(factors)
pixels = factors[0][:, None] * u + factors[1][:, None] + v
```

First, a math error: you want the *Cartesian product*, not the combinations.

Now, the actual syntax error: `itertools` produces a list of `[(i1, j1), (i2, j2)..]`, not a numpy array. So, for your final line to work you have to

1. `zip(*)` to convert the list to `(i1, i2), (j1, j2)` format
2. make it a numpy array
3. in the `factors[0], factors[1]` vectors, which are *1D*, add `[:, None]` to convert the to columns, so that broadcasting works.

Comment: Your solution works and is easy to understand. Unfortunately it is significantly slower than @w-m solution.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker: I know, I didn't write it as a proposed method, in terms of efficiency. Just wanted to explain why you get an error.